# Embedded CSS Media Queries Not Working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am new to CSS media queries, and I was first trying to get pdf/mp3/mp4 buttons to get centered on this page whenever a mobile device is using it (http://www.mannachurch.org/portfolio-type/recycled-junk/). Keep in mind for that I am using a highly modified wordpress theme.

So I tried experimenting to isolate this issue. However, I don't seem to have any control over using media queries and I can't even perform anything even on this simple HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style type="text/css">

body{background-color: blue;}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 599px) and (max-device-width : 600px) {
    body {background-color:black;
    }
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>This is an experiment<p/>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your media query only leaves a one pixel range to work with. Between 599 and 600. You would want something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 600px) {
    body {background-color:black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that just now, still doesn't work. Why is there a range to begin with? Can't I just say "at 600px do this to my content"?

Comment: Got it working in another example, but still cannot get it to work in this one.

Answer (score 2):

Add viewPort Meta tag in your   tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is reference : http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design

Comment: I did that and changed the width properties to just say this:  

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 600px) {
    body {background-color:black;
    }
}

Still, it will not work. Ugh... :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you fix you width properties as you have a 1px differencial

```
min-device-width : 599px
max-device-width : 600px
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked. This question was sparked from a theme I am trying to customize in wordpress. The editor in wordpress is REALLY wonky. At least now I know I'm doing the CSS media queries right. This is what worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style type="text/css">

/*-- EUREKA!!! IT works! */

body{background-color: blue;}

@media all and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 400px) {

        body{ 
        background-color:black;
                }

    }

@media all and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 760px) {

        body{ 
        background-color:black;
                }

    }

    @media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

        body{ 
        background-color:black;
                }

    }

</style>
</head>
```